# IPPeerCommon and IPPeerClient

Tags: delphi, cloud, delphi-xe3, uses-clause

I'm going over the cloud samples [CloudExplorer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE3/en/DataSnap.Cloud_Explorer_Sample) and CloudUpload provided by Embarcadero, and `IPPeerClient` and `IPPeerClient` are units listed under the `uses` clause. I'm trying to figure out what these units do for/with the cloud, but can't seem to find any information on them.

I tried finding the units to read through them, however attempting to select "Find Declaration" reveals there is no `IPPeerCommon.pas` or `IPPeerClient.pas`, and I can't seem to find it in my Delphi XE3 folders. Google/Embarcadero searching didn't return any links, which makes me feel like I'm missing something which may be obvious.

**What does using IPPeerCommon and IPPeerClient do**, whether for the cloud samples or in general. If there is in fact code for these two, then where would/should I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually all TCP/HTTP traffic in various Delphi client/server components (e.g. DataSnap) goes through an Indy implementation. The connection to Indy is not hard coded though, but goes through an abstraction layer. By using IPPeerClient and IPPeerServer you are actually pulling in Indy's IP implementation. 
Unfortunately this abstraction idea has been abandoned somewhat, since  System.Net.HTTPClient (which was introduced as an alternative HTTP client, directly using methods provided by the actual platform - Win, Mac, iOS, Android ...) does not provide the mechanisms to be just plugged in and replace Indy's HTTP access. You have to replace code manually instead ...